# Django: no such table snippets_snippet

Tags: python, django, serialization, code-snippets

I'm following this Django Rest tutorial on serialization: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#getting-started

I followed it pretty much to the letter. It gives the above error when I try to save a snippet.

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

snippet = Snippet(code='foo = "bar"\n')
snippet.save()
```

I'm working on Windows. The tutorial is made for Apple. I have had to enter some commands slightly differently for this reason. I have no idea if this has to do with what is wrong in this case.

I don't know where to even start in figuring out the problem here, so I could use any help. Thanks.

Comment: you forget to create the table : follow the instructions correctly python manage.py makemigrations snippets
python manage.py migrate

Comment: I missed the migrate step. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the migration (ie: forcing the db to corespond to what is defined by your new python code)
Do the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations snippets
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove db.sqlite3 as well as snippets/migrations. Later, create a folder named migrations inside snippets folder and create a `__init__.py` file inside snippets/migrations/ folder. Finally run:

`python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`

Be sure you are into the virtual environment with the correct python version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error refers to the models.py. Could you show the file so I can double check that too. Also there is a chance for unapllied migartions, double check if you've done this as well.